# New Green Card holder- Bank Accounts in India

Tags: united-states, india, resident

I and my wife recently (2 months ago) received our green cards (family - parent based). We came to US at the end of January, and received GCs in Sept. Due to Covid-19, we got stuck up in US. I opened bank account in US bank.

1. I am aware that we need to convert all our bank accounts in Indian banks to NRO / NRE. However we wont be able to go back to India until the covid situation is somewhat better in India. Is there a time limit to inform the bank about receipt of GCs to get our normal bank accounts to NRO / NRE. Can we do that when we go back to India?
2. In the preceding financial year (April 2019 to March 2020) we were in India for more than 7-8 months. At present, are we eligible for Indian resident? Am I eligible to transfer my money in my Indian bank to US bank via net banking ?

Answer (score 1):

If you stay for more than 180 days outside of India your status becomes NRI  and you must convert your savings account to NRO demat account to non-pins.

You can do it earlier, I.e before 180 days as well if you know you will be NRI.

For FY Apr 2019 to Mar 2020 you will be Resident Indian. For FY April 2020 to Mar 2021 you will be NRI.

Under liberalized remittance scheme you can transfer USD 250,000 per year without any issues. Note most banks don't offer international wire transfers via net banking, you have to visit in person.

Answer (score 0):

You were in India for seven months during 2019-20. You travelled out of India without the intention of staying out of India for an uncertain period (got stuck due to COVID).
You need to inform the bank about residency when you become a person resident outside India as per the FEMA. I presume that has happened  when you received two months ago. you can inform the bank via electronic medium (email) and get your status changed. The resident account shall be changed to NRO account. You will have to open a new NRE account if you need.
You can transfer money from India to US bank account. Is it possible via net banking ? Depends on your bank and your settings. SBI, HDFC etc. do allow international transfers via net banking.